# Duplicate values for Query on Account History object

Tags: apex, soql, accounthistory

When im running this

```
Select Account.name, NewValue, OldValue, IsDeleted from AccountHistory where Field = 'Owner' ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

in salesforce it is giving me two records for one change.

[image: Here is the screenshot for the same]

Answer (score 1):

**added based on comments**

If you need to get the history without the `Id`s, then you can use below code snippet:

```
List<AccountHistory> ach = [SELECT Id, Account.Name, Field, OldValue, NewValue 
                            FROM AccountHistory 
                            WHERE Field = 'Owner' 
                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
List<AccountHistory> targetAch = new List<AccountHistory>();
for(AccountHistory ah : ach)
    if(!(ah.NewValue instanceof Id))
    targetAch.add(ah);
```

`targetAch` will have `List<AccountHistory>` without `Id`s. If you need Ids only, then you can flip the `If` condition by removing `!`.

---

**Old answer**

The reference fields like `Owner`, `Parent` etc will be tracked for both `Id` and `Name` changes. So, for every change in record for these fields, 2 corresponding history records are created. Notice that even for custom lookup `Test_Object__c`, there will be 2 records created which references (1) Its `Id` and (2) Its `Name`

[image]

PS: I remember seeing this documentation sometime back but right now unable to find it, pls feel free to add the link here if someone finds it.

Comment: Okay. How do we get the single record ? I need this account data (without duplicate) for other logic to be processed further, any filter we need to consider here ?.

Comment: do you need only Id values?

Comment: No, I need the other values without Ids, anything works fine but i need only one from those two

Comment: added in answer

Comment: @RaJu is your issue solved?